# c program that converts numbers to roman numerals

Tags: c

My homework is to write a simple c program that converts numbers into roman numerals. The only functions that i am allowed  to use are printf and scanf. I have written the code, however i don't know how to print out numbers such as "25, 13, 93, 66" etc. Any help would be appreciated! thank you! (below is the written code)

```
int main(int arg, char *argv[]){    
int thousand, hundred, ten, single;
int number;

printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
scanf("%d", &number);

thousand = number + 0;
if (thousand == 1000) {
    printf("%d is represented as M in Roman numerals. \n", number);
} else if (thousand == 2000) {
    printf("%d is represented as MM in Roman numerals. \n", number);
} else if (thousand == 3000)  
    printf("%d is represented as MMM in Roman numerals. \n",number);

hundred = number + 0;   

if (hundred == 100) {
    printf("%d is represented as C in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (hundred == 200) {
    printf("%d is represented as CC in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (hundred == 300) {
    printf("%d is represented as CCC in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (hundred == 400) {
    printf("%d is represented as CD in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (hundred == 500) {
    printf("%d is represented as D in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (hundred == 600) {
    printf("%d is represented as DC in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (hundred == 700) {
    printf("%d is represented as DCC in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (hundred == 800) {
    printf("%d is represented as DCCC in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (hundred == 900) 
    printf("%d is represented as CM in Roman numerals. \n",number);

ten = number + 0;
if (ten == 10) {    
    printf("%d is represented as X in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (ten == 20) {
    printf("%d is represented as XX in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (ten == 30) {
    printf("%d is represented as XXX in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (ten == 40) {
    printf("%d is represented as XL in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (ten == 50) {
    printf("%d is represented as L in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (ten == 60) {
    printf("%d is represented as LX in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (ten == 70) {
    printf("%d is represented as LXX in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (ten ==80) {
    printf("%d is represented as LXXX in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (ten == 90)
    printf("%d is represented as XC in Roman numerals. \n",number);

single = number + 0;
if (single == 1) {
    printf("%d is represented as I in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (single == 2) {
    printf("%d is represented as II in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (single == 3) {
    printf("%d is represented as III in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (single == 4) {
    printf("%d is represented as IV in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (single == 5) {
    printf("%d is represented as V in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (single == 6) {
    printf("%d is represented as VI in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (single == 7) {
    printf("%d is represented as VII in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (single ==8) {
    printf("%d is represented as VIII in Roman numerals. \n",number);
} else if (single == 9)
    printf("%d is represented as IX in Roman numerals. \n",number);

if (number <= 0) {
    printf("%d can not be represented in Roman numerals. \n", number);
} else if (number > 3000) 
    printf("%d can not be represented in Roman numerals. \n", number);


   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: you should probably use a while/for loop. Start in the ones digit, and work your way up, adding the associated numeral as you go.

Comment: Consider having a consistent style with your codes. Consider either using curly braces `{ ... }` for all of your single-statement if-blocks, or not using them whenever there is and will be only a single statement.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to attempt to concatenate numbers using the following
hundred = number + 0;

This would simply result in number, as number + 0 = number.  If you wish to add a zero, multiply the number by 10.  As follows
hundred = number * 10;

As for software design, you may wish to return a non-zero number if the program fails to convert the number, as this can be analysed by other, calling programs/scripts.

I find it easier to view code when it has been properly formatted, with indentation, as this gives more of an overview of the code-flow and where the scopes fall.

I hope these little tips help :).

Comment: So are you suggesting i should not put in number = number + 0 and put maybe number = number + 1000 for the thousands and number = number + 100 for the hundreds? 

Thank you for replying!

Comment: Nope, as you are working in decimal, you can increment the number utilising * 10...  You appear to do `number = number + 0` in an attempt to add a nought to the end of your number, which simply doesn't work.  You must do `number = number * 10` to achieve this, unless I have the wrong end of the stick...

Comment: Ahh, okay thank you (:. That shortens my code alot if i put a while/for loop in and increment it by 10. However, it still doesn't solve for roman numerals such as 25, 26,11 etc. (the ones where you add two roman numerals together)

Answer (score 1):

```
void dec2romanstr(int num){
    int del[] = {1000,900,500,400,100,90,50,40,10,9,5,4,1}; // Key value in Roman counting
    char * sym[] = { "M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I" }; //Symbols for key values
    char res[64] = "\0";         //result string
    int i = 0;                   //
    while (num){                 //while input number is not zero
        while (num/del[i]){      //while a number contains the largest key value possible
            strcat(res, sym[i]); //append the symbol for this key value to res string
            num -= del[i];       //subtract the key value from number
        }
        i++;                     //proceed to the next key value
    }
    puts(res);
}
```

Comment: printf("%s",sym[i]) can be used instead of appending symbols to res string

Comment: Code only answers are usually [frowned upon](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258673/2596334). Try adding an [explination or code comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269981/2596334). Thanks.

Comment: printf for sure is slower then strcat. A good implementation would use neither but just move the pointer

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct radix {
    int  digit;
    char roman;
    char romanNext;
} RADIX;


char *roman(int num, char *buff){
    static RADIX table[]={
        { 1000, 'M', '?' },
        {  100, 'C', 'D' },
        {   10, 'X', 'L' },
        {    1, 'I', 'V' }
    };
    int tableSize = sizeof(table)/sizeof(RADIX);
    int i, j, n;
    char *p;

    if(num < 0 || num >=4000){
        *buff='\0';
        return NULL;
    }
    for(i=0,p=buff;i<tableSize;i++){
        n = num / table[i].digit;
        if( 1 <= n && n <=3 ){
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                *p++=table[i].roman;
        } else if(n == 4){
            *p++=table[i].roman;
            *p++=table[i].romanNext;
        } else if(n == 5){
            *p++=table[i].romanNext;
        } else if(6<= n && n <=8){
            *p++=table[i].romanNext;
            for(j=0;j< n-5;++j)
                *p++=table[i].roman;
        } else if(n == 9){
            *p++=table[i].roman;
            *p++=table[i-1].roman;
        }
        num -= n * table[i].digit;
    }
    *p='\0';
    return buff;
}

int main(){
    int i, number[] = {25, 13, 93, 66};
    char buff[16];

    for(i=0;i < 4;++i){
        if(roman(number[i], buff))
            printf("%d is %s\n", number[i], buff);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion BLUEPIXY. However, i didn't understand half of the code because we haven't learnt it in class yes, therefore i will not be able to use it. Sorry. But thank you for answering! (:

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct {
    int value;
    char romanDgts[3];
} romanTable[] =    {{1000, "M"},
                    {900,   "CM"},
                    {500,   "D"},
                    {400,   "CD"},
                    {100,   "C"},
                    {90,    "XC"},
                    {50,    "L"},
                    {40,    "XL"},
                    {10,    "X"},
                    {9,     "IX"},
                    {5,     "V"},
                    {4,     "IV"},
                    {1,     "I"}};

char *intToRoman(int n)
{
    char *romanNumerals;
    int i = 0;

    romanNumerals = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);

    while (n) {
        while (n < romanTable[i].value)
            i++;
        while(n >= romanTable[i].value) {
            strcat(romanNumerals, romanTable[i].romanDgts);
            n -= romanTable[i].value;
        }
    }

    return romanNumerals;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int number;
    char *result;

    printf("Input a decimal number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    if(number < 0  || number > 3999) {
        printf("Input must be within the range from 1 to 3999.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    result = intToRoman(number);
    puts(result);

    free(result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks MuertoExcobito. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int num,reminder,counter;
scanf("%d",&num);
for(counter=1;counter<=num/1000;counter++)
    printf("M");
reminder = num%1000;

for(counter=reminder/900;counter==1;counter++)
    printf("CM");
reminder = reminder%900;

for(counter=reminder/500;counter==1;counter++)
    printf("D");
reminder = reminder%500;

for(counter=reminder/400;counter==1;counter++)
    printf("CD");
reminder = reminder%400;

for(counter=1;counter<=reminder/100;counter++)
    printf("C");
reminder = reminder%100;

for(counter=reminder/90;counter==1;counter++)
    printf("XC");
reminder = reminder%90;

for(counter=reminder/50;counter==1;counter++)
    printf("L");
reminder = reminder%50;

for(counter=reminder/40;counter==1;counter++)
    printf("XL");
reminder = reminder%40;

for(counter=reminder/10;counter>=1;counter--)
    printf("X");
reminder = reminder%10;

for(counter=reminder/9;counter==1;counter++)
    printf("IX");
reminder = reminder%9;

for(counter=reminder/5;counter==1;counter++)
    printf("V");
reminder = reminder%5;

for(counter=reminder/4;counter==1;counter++)
    printf("IV");
reminder = reminder%4;

for(counter=reminder;counter>=1;counter--)
    printf("I");
```

}

Long(43lines) but simple right!!.....

Answer (score -1):

The problem is really daunting ,at least at a beginner level, ... since you have mentioned to use only basic functions then numbers below **1000** can be easily printed using this solution of mine:

```
# include<stdio.h>
main()
{
  int num,r,t,z,count=1;
  char c1='I',c2='V',c3='X',c4='L',c5='C',c6='D',c7='M';
  printf("enter the number");
  scanf("%d",&num);
  r=num%10;
  z=num/100;
  t=num%100;
  while(count<=3)
  {
      if(count==2)
      {
          z=(t-r)/10;
          c7='C';
          c6='L';
          c5='X';
      }
      if(count==3)
      {
          z=r;
          c7='X';
          c6='V';
          c5='I';
      }
      switch(z)
      {
          case 0:printf("");
          break;
          case 1:printf("%c",c5);
          break;
          case 2:printf("%c%c",c5,c5);
          break;
          case 3:printf("%c%c%c",c5,c5,c5);
          break;
          case 4:printf("%c%c",c5,c6);
          break;
          case 5:printf("%c",c6);
          break;
          case 6:printf("%c%c",c6,c5);
          break;
          case 7:printf("%c%c%c",c6,c5,c5);
          break;
          case 8:printf("%c%c%c%c",c6,c5,c5,c5);
          break;
          case 9:printf("%c%c",c5,c7);
          break;
          case 10:printf("%c",c7);
          break;
      }
      count++;
  }
}
```

Comment: OP is trying to learn. You should explain how your program works and/or why you did it this way and/or what the problem in the original code was.